# Is In.ReadLine line-buffered or not?

Tags: c#, io

I know that `In.Read` is Line-buffered because the carriage return `\r` and line feed `\f` are saved in the standard input stream so when I say:

```
int t = Console.In.Read();
int t1 = Console.In.Read(); 
int t2 = Console.In.Read();
```

`t1` is `13`(carriage return) and `t2` is `10`(line feed)

I have read somewhere that the `In.ReadLine` is Line-Buffered as well but when I say:

```
string? v = Console.In.ReadLine();
string? v1 = Console.In.ReadLine();
string? v2 = Console.In.ReadLine();
```

`v1` does not get the carriage return and `v2` does not get the line feed but thay get whatever I input in the console.
So can you please tell me how is `In.ReadLine` line-buffered?

Comment: Of course ReadLine has to buffer, unless considering special circumstances. It has to read as many characters until it comes either across a (supported) end-of-line marker or end-of-stream. If it were not buffering these characters (i.e. keeping/memorizing them somewhere) until it finds the end of the line/stream, how would it be able to return a line (string) with characters it didn't memorize when hunting for the end-of-line/stream? Note that not all types of streams allow going backward in the stream (say for example, a NetworkStream), so TextReader.ReadLine has to buffer in such cases...

Comment: Now, that doesn't mean ReadLine has _always_ to buffer. If a stream is seekable and thus the ReadLine method would be able to get backwards in the stream, it could technically memorize the starting position of a line in the stream instead of buffering the characters it reads, and then after finding the EOL/EOS go back to that stream position and reading the stream data of that line once more. Of course, reading the data from the stream once more can have an impact on performance, depending on the concrete stream implementation, so buffering still makes sense for perf reasons...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, thank you very much for the answer. This is really helpful but why don;y the `v1` and `v2` get the 13 and 10 respectively?

Comment: You could just look at [the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/215b39abf947da7a40b0cb137eab4bceb24ad3e3/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/TextReader.cs#L178) and see that it uses a `StringBuilder` to buffer the characters until it encoutners an LF/DR/null

Comment: @EricMovsessian, because that's the specified behavior of ReadLine. That behavior is also described in the method's documentation. Why it is like that? I don't know, i wasn't around when the API for ReadLine has been formulated and decided upon back in the days of .NET framework 1/2. But i guess it is typically not useful and rather an annoyance in most application scenarios to have strings that represents a single line to also have EOL markers dangling at their ends...